# TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Sage'

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, multiple-inheritance

#### `Marks` class

```
from Studentclass import Student
from Courseclass import Course

class Marks(Student, Course):
    def __init__(self, Sid,Cid, Mark):
        super().__init__(Sid,Cid)#Error line 7, in __init__ super().__init__(Sid,Cid) TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Sage'#
        self.Mark = Mark

    def __repr__(self):
        return '({},{},{})'.format(self.Sid, self.Cid, self.Mark)
```

#### Main code

```
from Studentclass import Student
from Courseclass import Course
from Marksclass import Marks

def read_populate_marks():
    with open("Marks.txt", "r") as m:
        marks_list = []
        for line in m:
            Sid, Cid, Mark = line.split(",")
            marks = Marks(int(Sid), int(Cid), int(Mark))#Error line 37
            marks_list.append(marks)
        return marks_list

print(read_populate_marks()
```

I am receiving an error when running this function telling me to pass Sage which is from the student class I only wish to call Sid. the same function works fine with other classes first time using multiple inheritance what should I do?

- student constructor is `(Sid,Sname,Sage)`
- course constructor is `(Cid,Cname,Cstudents)`.

Comment: Your design seems wrong : a Mark isn't BOTH a Student and a Course, it may contain them as attribut, it IS not

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your model isn't good, a `Mark` **IS** not both a Student and a Course (like a Cow **IS** an Animal), but the Mark is defined by the correlation of a `Student` and `Course` so it may have them as attributes.

```
class Marks:
    student_id: int
    course_id: int
    mark = int

    def __init__(self, Sid, Cid, Mark):
        super().__init__()
        self.student_id = Sid
        self.course_id = Cid
        self.mark = Mark

    def __repr__(self):
        return '({},{},{})'.format(self.student_id, self.course_id, self.mark)
```

That call is now coherent

```
marks = Marks(int(Sid), int(Cid), int(Mark))
```

Comment: This is Amazing it works, Thanks I have been stuck on this for the last 4 hours Thank you very much. is this what is called multiple inheritance? Also, no imports needed?

Comment: @Kittens Nope, YOUR code was multiple inheritance. as you don't need Student and Course class, no you don't

Comment: So, it is not possible to use multiple inheritance for class Marks? since i am not giving values to super classes this what i wished to do based on our project diagram

Comment: @Kittens Could share that diagram ? Inheritance means that a class is a subclass of another, like a Dog IS an Animal, a Cat IS an Animal. But is Mark a Student or a Course ? Not at all, so no inheritance needed here

Comment: the code has to use multiple inheritance this is the problem I am facing I need to call specific attributes from the parents classes as columns in the txt file so later on i will be using this code for database purposes

Comment: @Kittens Sorry but I can't help you more, Don't see any inheritance needed